# Iterate object in dictionary with ordered form in swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, ios8.1

I have a dictionary i want to iterate it in ordered form as the objects are in the dictionary, but after iterating it is iterating in random order. Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i want to iterate it in ordered form as the objects are in the dictionary" Meaningless. A dictionary has _no order_.

Comment: You have to implement custom dictionary type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a dictionary but you can sort its keys as follow:

```
let myDict: [String:String] = ["car":"blue", "watch":"black", "bike": "red"]

for key in myDict.keys.array.sorted(<) {
    let value  = myDict[key]!
    println("\(key) = \(value)")
}


let dashboardItemsTuples : [(String , String)] = [("All Cards" , "cards" ), ("Cards by Topic" , "cards_topic"), ("Lessons" , "lesson" ), ("Audio" , "audio"), ("Video" ,"video") ,( "Ebook" , "ebook") , ("Bookmarked Cards" , "bookmark_cards" ), ("Upgrade","upgrade") , ("Downloads" ,"downloads")]

for (key,value) in dashboardItemsTuples {
    println("\(key)=\(value)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is sorting alphabetically not as my dictionary generated.

Comment: Show your dictionary I can show you  how to sort it

Comment: Could you tell me how to take object as they are inserted into the dictionary.

Comment: You should use Swift native type Dictionary

Comment: let dashboardItems : [String : String] = ["All Cards" : "cards" , "Cards by Topic": "cards_topic", "Lessons": "lesson" , "Audio":"audio", "Video" :"video" , "Ebook": "ebook" , "Bookmarked Cards" :"bookmark_cards" , "Upgrade":"upgrade" , "Downloads" :"downloads"]

Comment: You can't you would need an array

Comment: An Array would keep the order you insert the items a Dictionary won't

Comment: You can have an array of tuples

Comment: or you can create an array to use as index. Everytime you add a key value to your dictionary you add the key to your index array